# Hash/Encrypt config file information

Tags: database, security, hash, web-applications, server

Usually, applications and their configs are inside the same machine and when somebody hacks that machine then can access the config file and access to database although (via DB username and password that located on that config file). What if we hash the config file information and then use that file instead of a pure text file? Is there any better idea? Let's say that I don't want to use any cloud infra, there is just a single machine.

Answer (score 2):

Hashing is a [one-way process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) - most commonly used to verify that information hasn't been tampered with. So hashing your config file gives you an essentially meaningless string of characters, which you cannot use to establish a database connection.

You can, of course, encrypt the config file, but then you have the same problem - an attacker who has access to the web application in theory can retrieve the decryption key, and work out how to decrypt the config; they may even be able to find out at run time by inspecting the memory of the server process.

The major point is that an attacker who has access to your web server is almost impossible to stop - they can presumably access all the traffic going in and out of your server, they can read all the files on the server (or at least the ones the web application user can read), they may be able to execute arbitrary code on the server. Protecting against this eventuality is not the best use of your time - it's like investing in locks to the bedrooms in case the front door is insecure. Much better to fix the front door.

The best solution to this problem is to let the people who built whatever web language/framework you're using solve it. You don't specify the language/framework, but read up on the security guidance for your toolset, and implement the recommendations. Also look at the [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Hashing functions are one-way functions. Once you hash a config file, you won't be able to "un-hash" it for the application to process it. Encryption is probably what most people use, but even then can still be susceptible to reverse engineering.